# Does Hoffman constant keep the same after a very tiny perturbation on the polyhedron such that the bases are even unchanegd?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, linear-programming, polyhedra

Suppose that $P$ is a polyhedron represented by
$$P:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: A x \le b \} \text{ for }A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n},\ b \in \mathbb{R}^m,$$
and $P$ contains interior points. Moreover, the *extreme points* (or *basic feasible solutions*, *vertex points*) of $P$ are
$\{x^1, x^2,\dots, x^k\},$
associated with *bases* $\{B_1,B_2,\dots,B_k\},$
denoting the sets of the indices for the constraints holding at equality. The *Hoffman constant* of $P$ is defined by
$$
H(A,b):=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus P}\frac{\min_{y\in P}\|x - y\|}{\|(Ax - b)^+\|} \ .
$$

Suppose that now we know there is a tiny $\epsilon > 0$, such that for any small perturbation $|\delta| \le \epsilon$ on the first component of $b$, the bases of all the extreme points of
$$P_\delta:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: A x \le b + \delta e_1 \}$$
are still $\{B_1,B_2,\dots,B_k\}$.

I guess
$$
H(A,b) = H(A,b + \delta e_1) \text{ for any } |\delta| < \epsilon . 
$$
But is it true?

It looks obviously true in toy examples, for example, when $P$ are rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I just had some thoughts about it. Will post an answer later.